# What does "handle" mean in this form?

Tags: verbs, nouns

I have to fill a form but have no idea what the "handle" means (see picture) and what I have to fill in there.

Its purpose is to change the ownership of a domain.
[image]

Comment: It is impossible to say, and unwise to guess. I would contact whoever you are sending the form to and ask for clarification.

Comment: Maybe it's for the secondary owner, like the co-manager.
Since there is one field called *handle* after each function's field. Perharps it is for the secondary owner.

Comment: The first Google result for me: [NIC handle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIC_handle).

Comment: I imagine it refers to a form of identification, like choster's link or like a Twitter handle.

Comment: it must be what is described choster's link that they're after regardless of what else handle might mean... in my -humble- opinion of course

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the specific meaning of a particular word in a legal form - not about English Language.

Answer (score 2):

Two possible relevant meanings for **handle** (OED).  The first seems most likely to answer the OP.  Presumably the OP letter is asking you to provide a/the short name for the various people on the list.

> A personal name; a nickname; specifically an identifying nickname used by a CB radio operator or (later) a user of an online forum, etc (originally US).

- 1956   N. Algren Walk on Wild Side i. 75   *The name is Kitty Twist..not my real handle of course. It's just what they took to callin' me in The Home.*

> (More fully *a **handle** to one's name*). A title of rank, honour, respect, or profession; spec. (chiefly Brit.) a title of noble rank.

- 1822 J. Mitford My Cousin in Army iv. 105   *The men..With pretty handles to their names;—The Hons. and Barts. and K.C.B.'s.*

Comment: +1 Some websites use the term "handle" rather than 'login', 'username', 'user ID', etc.

Answer (score 0):

When I googled, I found the following two as the meanings of 'handle':
".

> a name or nickname.
>   *"that's some handle for a baby"*
>
> a person’s username on an online forum or social media site.
>   *"she's changed her Twitter handle"*

The 'Change of Ownership', it being the ownership of an internet domain, 'handle' can mean 'a nick name or a username'.